How do I add custom Intellisense in VScode latex-workshop?
When I was writing my graduation thesis, I used a template made by my senior that met the school's requirements. There is a \citing{} command in it, which can add a literature citation in the upper right corner. I want to add this command to IntelliSense,but it cannot automatically prompt the references in the reference.bib like \cite{}.
How can I modify it?
In addition, I am a programming novice, please explain in detail.




Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
